# Add 1 to a label value

Tags: vba, integer, label, addition

I am a newbie and I have tried to add one to a label every time you click a button I have tried

```
Label1 = Label1 + 1
```

But I get an error saying:

> "Operator `+` is not defined for types `System.Windows.Forms.Label` and `Integer`."

Can any one help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
Label1.Text
```

property.

But it's string(in c#) so you also need to convert it from string to int, add 1, and convert result to string and put it to property

Answer (score 0):

Label1.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(Label1.Text) + 1).ToString()

Label is a Control, the text on it is assigned to using the Text property.